# Image Zoom while onClick and onTouch perform toghether

Tags: android, android-imageview, ontouch, gesturedetector

I am performing onClick and `onTouch` on same `ImageView` and handle it with the use of `gestureDetector` which work fine. Open Gallery on `onClick` and set selected image on ImageView and after that image move,zoom in,zoom out etc.. perform.But issue is image zoomed while image set on imageView and i am analyze that it is because of `scaleType=Matrix`. How can i manage `scaleType` for solve this problem.?

```
private GestureDetector gestureDetectorOnClick;

gestureDetectorOnClick = new GestureDetector(this,
                new SingleTapConfirm());

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;
        if (gestureDetectorOnClick.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            v.performClick();
        }
         else {
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                matrix.set(imageView.getImageMatrix());
                startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - startPoint.x,
                            event.getY() - startPoint.y);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(midPoint, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                break;
            }
            imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint("FloatMath")
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

private class SingleTapConfirm extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: my  image Zoomed while set in imageView. If i remove scaleType=matrix than my image set properly but scaleType=matrix is compulsary for image zoom and move.

Comment: so do not remove `scaleType=matrix`

Comment: yes, but than how can i solve image zoom issue.?

Comment: what zoom? what you mean?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/efLyh  see this link.

Comment: I think, you problem is because matrix for new image save old values for scaled before images. You need to clear matrix values when open new image.

Comment: then set scaleType to "matrix" at runtime (not in xml) after your image view draws the image for the first time - use `ViewTreeObserver` for that

Comment: when i click on image first call else part and than perform click event. and i set scaleType in else part.